# TidfVectorizer - TypeError : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit TfidfVectorizer object to list of video game reviews, but for some reason I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 50000, use_idf = True, ngram_range=(1,3),
                                   preprocessor = data_preprocessor.preprocess_tokenized_review)

print(train_set_x[0])
%time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set_x)
```

And here is the error message:

```
I haven't gotten around to playing the campaign but the multiplayer is solid and pretty fun. Includes Zero Dark Thirty pack, an Online Pass, and the all powerful Battlefield 4 Beta access.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1379             Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.
   1380         """
-> 1381         X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1382         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1383         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
    867 
    868         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
--> 869                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
    870 
    871         if self.binary:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    790         for doc in raw_documents:
    791             feature_counter = {}
--> 792             for feature in analyze(doc):
    793                 try:
    794                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    264 
    265             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 266                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    267 
    268         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    239             return self.tokenizer
    240         token_pattern = re.compile(self.token_pattern)
--> 241         return lambda doc: token_pattern.findall(doc)
    242 
    243     def get_stop_words(self):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Note that the first part of the output represents one of the reviews from my video game dataset. If anyone has any idea what is going on, I would appreciate the help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is caused by the `data_preprocessor.preprocess_tokenized_review` function (which you didn't share).

Prove (using default `preprocessor=None`):

```
In [19]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

In [20]: X = ["I haven't gotten around to playing the campaign but the multiplayer is solid and pretty fun. Includes Zero Dark Thirty pack, an Onlin
    ...: e Pass, and the all powerful Battlefield 4 Beta access."]

In [21]: tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=50000, use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,3))

In [22]: r = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X)

In [25]: r
Out[25]:
<1x84 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 84 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

so it's working just fine when we don't pass any value for `preprocessor` parameter.

Comment: I will look into it. But if I dont pass any preprocessor argukent my data becomes really messy. I need to remove all the numbers punc etc. And thank you for your help btw